# Is this question OK to be asked?

Tags: discussion

A user answered/commented in https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/8819/2643 that (paraphrasing) one's reputation might suffer if they publish in not-so-highly-ranked conferences.

Based on this I want to ask following question. Let me know if the wording is fine before it gets any close votes.

> What are the disadvantages in publishing in national conferences?

Comment: Did you ask it now?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would rate this as "off-topic," but board members may always think differently. However, I would frame the question in a more "neutral" way and ask the question as "Can I only publish in top-ranked proceedings?"

Comment: Or "Should I only...." (rather than "can")

Comment: "Can I only?" this is an (easy) yes or no, and it would be no. Anyone _can_ publish wherever they are accepted. It would not be a useful question. "Should I only?" is (completely) opinionated and would be (or should be) closed as such. "What are the disadvantages" should be an answerable question and I would not VtC.